# Windows application TCP payload (md5) Possible to replicate?

Tags: tcp, md5, wireshark

been searching for hours, but can't solve it. I am trying to replicate a packet sent by a windows application to speed up a task however I cannot understand the payload structure for the server to accept it.

I attached an image below. Is there any way to see what structure I'm sending the data- so I can replicate with new info and encrypt to md5

New to this and Wireshark. I appreciate any guidance I could get.
Or to be told it's not possible.

Take care, thanks in advance.

[image: Text]

Comment: Fiddler might also be an option for you: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Modify-Traffic/Tasks/CustomizeRequest

Comment: @FoggyDay thank you for your response. Yes I tried Fiddler, but no HTTP/s requests are being sent. Only TCP or UDP